# org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser checkXrefOffsets SEVERE: Can't find the object 8 0 (origin offset 0)

Tags: java, pdfbox

We are using pdfbox 1.8.8 for extracting text from pdf files in my application. there is an issue with the pdfbox where it logs the error "org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser checkXrefOffsets  SEVERE: Can't find the object 8 0 (origin offset 0) " but not throwing it to handle the issue. Finally it returns the text in different unknown language. We couldn't upgrade pdfbox version due to application doesn't have quality test cases.

Here is the code:

```
     PDDocument pdDocument = null;
     File tmpfile = File.createTempFile(String.format("txttmp-%s", UUID.randomUUID().toString()), null);
    // pdDocument= PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(sourceFile),true);
     pdDocument =PDDocument.loadNonSeq(sourceFile, new RandomAccessFile(tmpfile, "rw"));
     PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
     int pages = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
     for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
         //Set up the text stripper to grab just one page worth of text
         pdfTextStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
         pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(page);
         pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(page);
         String pageText = pdfTextStripper.getText(pdDocument);
}
```

Comment: Re text extraction, see these: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction (applies to 1.8 as well). The error means that it can't find an object in an object stream. Which won't help you much, but it means your PDF is likely damaged. (even if "but it displays in Adobe Reader!".

Comment: Please share the pdf for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. pdf box 2.0 extract text from same pdf without any issues. i couldn't upgrade pdfbox version due to application other constraints. is there a way i could throw exception in this scenario so that users can do manual text extraction.

Comment: No, the error is swallowed.